# What is the difference between the host values in "Current user" vs "Connection" (in mysql status)

Tags: mysql, networking, localhost, credentials, privileges

I am troubleshooting a MySQL privileges problem.

I want to connect to MySQL on the local server, but refer to it by it's LAN name (so I can use the same user/pass/host on several web-nodes).

I have included credentials in the privilege tables for both a `%.lan` and a `localhost` user.

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user where user = 'mysqluser';
+-----------+---------------------+
| user      | host                |
+-----------+---------------------+
| mysqluser | %.lan               |
| mysqluser | localhost           |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

However, when I try to login, I get the error message

```
[systemuser@servername.mydomain.com ~]$ mysql -u mysqluser -p -h servername.mydomain.com.lan

Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'servername.mydomain.com'
```

Note that `servername.mydomain.com.lan` does resolve to a `192.168.%` IP; i.e. it's in my `/etc/hosts` file. Moreover, reverse DNS for the IP in question resolves as expected.

```
[systemuser@servername.mydomain.com ~]$ dig -x 192.168.X.Y
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
Y.X.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN  PTR servername.mydomain.com.lan.
```

If I temporarily grant privileges to `'mysqluser'@'%'` and login, MySQL reports

```
mysql> status
...
Current user:       mysqluser@servername.mydomain.com
...
Connection:         servername.mydomain.com.lan via TCP/IP
...
```

Why is the host for my `Current user` not equal to the host for my `Connection`?

What I am doing/assuming incorrectly? I should note that my arrangement was working as intended (for weeks), on two farms on a common LAN, then both, independent MySQL instances suddenly started rejecting MySQL connections.

Comment: From the SQL server, does reverse DNS resolution work for the IP addresses in question?

Comment: Yes -- question updated.